Symfony form type error "Can't get a way to read the property"
Company.php

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CompanyRepository::class)]
class Company implements \Stringable
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity: CompanyPrice::class, mappedBy: 'company', cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    private CompanyPrice $price;

CompanyPrice.php

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CompanyPriceRepository::class)]
class CompanyPrice
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    /**
     * @var Collection<int, CompanyZoneLimitPrice>
     */
    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'price', targetEntity: CompanyZoneLimitPrice::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    private Collection $carrierZoneLimitPrices;


CompanyType.php

class CompanyType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    #[\Override]
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        /** @var Company */
        $company = $builder->getData();

        $builder
            ->add('price', CompanyPriceType::class, [
                'data' => $company->getPrice(),
            ])

CompanyPriceType.php

class CompanyPriceType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    #[\Override]
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        /** @var CompanyPrice */
        $companyPrice = $builder->getData();

        $builder
            ->add('carrierZoneLimitPrices', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => CompanyZoneLimitPriceType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
            ])

I have other variables as well in company price but it seems I am only gettting the error on this variable name only...
But when I try to render I get:
Can't get a way to read the property "carrierZoneLimitPrices" in class "App\Entity\Company\CompanyPrice".
Normally I can get the data just fine: $company->getPrice()->getZoneLimitPrices();
I dont want to use 'mapped' => false
What I am missing here ?

$builder
->add('price', CompanyPriceType::class, [
'data' => $company->getPrice(), // can you remove data from there
])

Still same issue, I also have other variables that work fine.

in CompanyPrice.php you have a contructor where you initialize: $this->carrierZoneLimitPrices = new ArrayCollection();

Yes, I have there as well, should I clear my cache ? Can it be a problem ?

What is the name of the getter for the carrierZoneLimitPrices property in your CompanyPrice class? You say that if you use getZoneLimitPrices it works, so I'm assuming your getter is named getZoneLimitPrices.
But since your property is called carrierZoneLimitPrices, Symfony expects the getter to be named getCarrierZoneLimitPrices, which is different from the one you're using.
Try renaming your getter to getCarrierZoneLimitPrices?

OMG!!! YES. that was it. Thanks so much
